# Disable Stripe card editing from SDK interface

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I have the following code which should show a stripe SDK interface where to add a card and register the card in the system.

```
PaymentSheet.Address address = new PaymentSheet.Address(
                    PersistentManager.getCityForId(HVariant.getCityVariant()).getDisplayName(),
                    HVariant.getCountryVariant(),
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    HVariant.getCountryVariant());
            PaymentSheet.BillingDetails.Builder billingDetails =
                    new PaymentSheet.BillingDetails.Builder().address(address);

            PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration customerConfiguration = new PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
                    resp.getStripe().getCustomer(),
                    resp.getStripe().getEphemeralKey()
            );
            mPaymentSheet.presentWithSetupIntent(
                    resp.getStripe().getClientSecret(),
                    new PaymentSheet.Configuration(
                            "Avara",
                            customerConfiguration,
                            null,
                            null,
                            billingDetails.build()
                    )
            );
```

[image]

If no cards exist on the user, it opens the sheet where to input the card and it registers the card.
If there already is a card on the user, it opens the sheet but one where you can see the existing card and it lets you add a new one. This sheet has an `Edit` button which when pressed, I can delete the card from stripe. That really ruins the apps core business logic as the user needs to always have a card added in the system.

How can i disable the Delete card functionality from the interface? I found there's a `setCanDeletePaymentOptions` on the `PaymentSessionConfig` class, but I have no idea how to set that to he `paymentSheet`

Comment: I don't know stripe much but isn't user able to delete the card other way too (like stripe website)?

Comment: i don't believe so, no. it's only linked to the account in the app, to this specific app so no.

Comment: Not possible today, definitely a feature request for Stripe to add.

Comment: I am asking because for me you are fixing wrong thing. You shouldn't care how many cards user has. You only need to bother if there's one **when needed**.

Comment: I don't care how many, my problem is that he can delete all of them and leave the system without a card. And we need a card for background payments on the server-side ... so that's my problem, and that's why i want to disable card deletion from the strip interface.

Comment: @karllekko It's already implemented, it's a merge since 2020 https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/pull/2505

Comment: @AndreiBogdan yep but that's only applicable to the legacy PaymentSession, it doesn't work for the PaymentSheet(the component you're using), unfortunately, Stripe needs to re-implement it for that component.

Comment: hmm, so you're saying the PaymentSession thing is deprecated? Is this deprecated? https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic

Comment: I am still not buying your argumentation. Having no cards is the same as having one that you can charge for any reason (like valid card but no funds). So again, you fixing wrong thing for me

Comment: @AndreiBogdan yes, https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/basic is not really recommended(though it can be used), PaymentSheet (what you have in the screenshots/code in your question) is the modern and supported integration, it's just missing this particular feature right now unfortunately.

Comment: gotcha. could you write this as a response, please, so I can accept it ?